# Calculation of sum incorrect when digits over 10 million

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a textfield (numbers only) and a UILabel which I am adding together with the use of a button.  The UILabel displays the answer and the Textfield goes blank on calculation. The calculations and the functionality mentioned, works fine until I start wanting to add numbers more than 10Million.  The UILabel displays an answer of -2147483648.  The calculation I did to get me to this result was 0 + 1000000000.

I haven't set any limits on the character lengths of either field, so unsure why this is happening.

Here is the code for my calculation:

```
-(IBAction)addtotal2;{

float x = ([numberTextField.text floatValue]);
float y = ([dtotal.text floatValue]);
dtotaler = x + y;
dtotal.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",dtotaler];
numberTextField.text = @"";
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",dtotaler] forKey:@"saveDtotal"];
[userDefaults synchronize];
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're experiencing an overflow.

Use `double` instead of `float` and you should fix the problem.

```
double x = ([numberTextField.text doubleValue]);
double y = ([dtotal.text doubleValue]);
```

**EDIT**

As noted in the comments, the problem may be an integer overflow on the `dtotaler` variable, i.e. it may be an `int` too small for holding the result.

If that's the case, change the type of `dtotaler` to `NSInteger`, which on iOS is a type synonym for `long`

```
#if __LP64__ || TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED || TARGET_OS_IPHONE || TARGET_OS_WIN32 || NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64
typedef long NSInteger;
typedef unsigned long NSUInteger;
#else
typedef int NSInteger;
typedef unsigned int NSUInteger;
#endif
```

Comment: More probably an integer overflow :-) (-2147483648 is -2^31, and the %d format if for integers)

Comment: You're right. Added to the post ;)

Comment: Using a `double` wouldn't help here because presumably `dtotaler` is an `int`.

Comment: Great Thanks dude, that worked.  However now it falls over with any digits over 10 Billion, I doubt that I will need it for that much, but just in case any ideas for a number this big?

Comment: @Mustafa: Use `long long int` (about 19 decimal digits) or `NSDecimalNumber` (about 38 decimal digits).

Comment: @GabrielePetronella: `long` is 32-bit on the iPhone.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `double` for large value as `float` is `32-bit` and double is `64-bit` and can contain large value.